# MVCjquqery $(document).ready .load method is not called

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, document-ready, url.action

I am doing an `MVC5` `Application`..

I am rendering two `partial views` from controller method called from `$(document).ready` of the main view. But one method is never called.

Here is my view

```html
<div class="dvPpal">
    <div class="dvMenuIzqEmpty">
        <div style="float:left;width:100%;height:20px;margin-bottom:20px">
        </div>
        <div style="float:left;width:100%;margin-left:25px; ">
            <img class="ImgNick" src="~/Content/Images/Iconos/PhotosSmall.png" />
        </div>

        <div style="float:left;width:100%;height:30px;" class="Sees">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="UserUpload">
    </div>
    <div class="dvRightPnl">
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my call

```html
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
        FormCreateEdit();
        $("#dvRightPnl").load('@Url.Action("GetUploadsByUser", "Uploads")');
        $("#UserUpload").load('@Url.Action("GetUploadData", "Uploads", new { Upload_id = 0 })');
 });
 </script>
```

My controller method looks like this

```html
 public async Task<PartialViewResult> GetUploadData(long Upload_id = 0)
        {
        return null;
        }

 public async Task<PartialViewResult> GetUploadsByUser()
        {
        return null;
        }
```

Only `GetUploadData` is called.

The method `GetUploadsByUser` is never called?

What I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it's never called, rather than just not producing any output? Have you tried adding a `console.log` to see how far it gets? Are any error messages displayed in the console? Are you sure that `#dvRightPnl` loads?

Comment: if one is being called, the other is being called.

Comment: Yes, is never called, but I just fixed it.. I am Answer it.. thanks

Comment: eh, no, .load is called regardless of whether or not elements existed in the collection, the difference is whether or not an ajax request is sent.

Comment: @KevinB Correct me if I'm wrong... `.load()` isn't only called once the element loads?

Comment: no, the element loading is irrelevant to the .load method in modern versions of jquery.

Comment: @KevinB Okay, thanks, gotta brush up on my reading....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you just need to fix a typo.  Your script calls:

```
$("#dvRightPnl").load('@Url.Action("GetUploadsByUser", "Uploads")');
```

but your HTML assigns `dvRightPnl` as a class, not an ID:

```
<div class="dvRightPnl">
```

If you make them both the same (either change the jQuery selector to `$(".dvRightPnl")` or change the div in your HTML to `<div id="dvRightPnl">`) that should fix your problem.

Answer (score -1):

As soon as I saw the question, I realized my mistake...

Ht method that is never called i bind it to a div with `class=dvRightPnl`. I have to set `id=dvRightPnl` instead..

Insted of using

`<div class="dvRightPnl">  </div>`

I have to use

```
<div id="dvRightPnl">   </div>
```